# User input and retrieving it in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently trying using two modules in python, I am trying to have one module take user input and store it. But I cannot figure how to retrieve the data from the input module. I have imported everything but this only runs my input again from the def in the input module. Below is an example of my input module. How to I return this value from the user and use it in my other module to do calculations with?

```
def test():
   test = int(input("numbers:"))
   return test
```

Comment: Need to be more specific. What does the other module look like and what's not working?

Comment: Not really clear what you mean. What is: *"this only runs my input again from the def in the input module"*? The code soes what it should do (`python3`) but I'd suggest you should decide what to do with incorrect input.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean you use two files, and you need to use the information from the test function on the other file. Then, assuming you test file name is `testfile.py`, I would go with:

```
import testfile
num = testfile.test() # This will store the number recieved in the test() function in the variable num
print('Recieved number from user:', num)
```